# Store Gremlin graph in local DynamoDB

Tags: titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

Instead of using AWS, I am using its local available DynamoDB database and creating a graph in the Gremlin console.

My PC is using `Gremlin-version=3.0.1.incubating` and `Titan-version=1.0.0`

My question: How to save a graph in my local DynamoDB so that I can retrieve it back whenever I wish? (E.g. after computer restart).

I have tried a lot, using `save()` or `commit()` graph. But I always got an error:

```
g.commit()
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph
  .GraphTraversalSource.commit() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), computer(), collect(), wait(long), computer(java.lang.Class), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I am using `Tinkerpop 3`.

Answer (score 4):

Relevant documentation links:

- [Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/README.md)
- [Running DynamoDB on Your Computer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html)

As Filipe mentioned, `g.commit()` throws an exception because there is no `commit()` method on `g` which is a [`GraphTraversalSource`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html). I suggested that you use `graph.tx().commit()`, where `graph.tx()` gets the [`Transaction`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Transaction.html#commit--) from the [`Graph`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Graph.html#tx--). In the comments we found out that you were trying to `commit()` a transaction on a `TinkerGraph`, which does not support transactions.

You need to instantiate a **`TitanGraph`**, not a `TinkerGraph`. This commonly done with a [properties file](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html#_loading_the_graph_of_the_gods_into_titan), and there is a DynamoDB Local [example properties file](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/src/test/resources/dynamodb-local.properties) in the `dynamodb-titan-storage-backend` repository. Make sure to update the `storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint` to match your configuration. If you are using the Titan Server directions from the DynamoDB-Titan link, the port is [`4567`](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L19). If you are using the directions from the DynamoDB local link above, the default port is `8000`.

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb-local.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> v0 = graph.addVertex('name', 'jason'); v1 = graph.addVertex('name', 'mustaffa'); v0.addEdge('helps', v1)
==>e[175-39k-1lh-374][4232-helps->4144]
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
==>null
```

Also note, the DynamoDB-Titan directions end up starting an in-memory DynamoDB Local instance. This behavior can be changed by commenting out the `-inMemory` argument the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L216).

Comment: Might be helpful   I will surely notice it and get back    BTW  thanks for the wonderful suggestion..!       :)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to commit your traversal `g`. You should be attempting to commit your graph like so: `graph.commit()`.

`g` is the traversal which is initialised as such: `g = graph.traversal()` and it cannot be committed.

Comment: hey, i have tried it using the above command but it shows the following error : graph.commit()
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph.commit() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: compute(), compute(java.lang.Class), wait(), collect(), wait(long), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)
Display stack trace? [yN]                                                                                                  Can u solve the problem.....

Comment: [TinkerGra‌ph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#tinkergraph-gremlin) is an in-memory graph only so it cannot be commited. Check how you are initialising your graph. Since it looks like you are trying to use titan on top of dynamo you should probable take a look [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html)

Comment: absolutely right as i am using titan on top of it. but i have not not know how could this be save the graph and retrieve it

Comment: You are incorrectly initialising a TinkerGraph. You should be initialising a titan graph as detailed [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html)

Comment: `graph.tx().commit()`

Comment: I have a problem actually i have installed dynamodb local at one place from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html