# save gremlin graph usinf gremlin console

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin-server

how to save graph made in gremlin console in local dynamo uses tinker popup 3 
My PC is using Gremlin-version=3.0.1.incubating and Titan-version=1.0.0

I have tried as many and give a lot time by using
 graph.tx().commit()

But shows ::   Graph does not support transactions
Display stack trace? [yN]

Comment: you should edit/update your previous question rather than starting a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841236/store-gremlin-graph-in-local-dynamodb