# store graph via DynamoDB local

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin

I'm trying to get Titan with Dynamo DB local. I've followed the steps from git-hub.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html

In gremlin console I've created the graph but i can't commit() or save() the graph.

how can i get the location of the Tinker-graph created via gremlin console? And which format graph is to be saved?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/40871366/5025129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store gremlin graph in local dynamodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841236/store-gremlin-graph-in-local-dynamodb)