# create multiple vertices in gremlin graph in local dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin-server

I have to create multiple vertices in gremlin graph in its console using local DynamoDB few commands.

Uses := TitanDB

Storage Backend := DynamoDB

Server := Gremlin server

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same example I provided [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40871366/5025129)

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb-local.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> v0 = graph.addVertex('name', 'jason'); v1 = graph.addVertex('name', 'mustaffa'); v0.addEdge('helps', v1)
==>e[175-39k-1lh-374][4232-helps->4144]
gremlin> graph.tx().commit()
==>null
```

It creates 2 vertices and 1 edge. This example shows a direct connection to the Titan graph without using a Gremlin Server.

If you want to connect to a Gremlin Server, the syntax is largely the same. First create a remote connection to the Gremlin Server, then you have to use `:>` or `:submit` to send the request to the server. Also note that you don't need to explicitly call `graph.tx().commit()` because the transaction is automatically committed on each remote request.

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Connected - localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :> v0 = graph.addVertex('name', 'jason'); v1 = graph.addVertex('name', 'mustaffa'); v0.addEdge('helps', v1)
==>e[17c-3b4-1lh-3a8][4288-helps->4256]
```

Comment: how i want to create 50 vertices at one command having tinkerpopup 3  in gremlin server and its console

Comment: As i use  graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb-local.properties')
                                                                                                       Backend shorthand unknown: conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb-local.properties
                                                                                                           Display stack trace? [yN]

Comment: To create 50 vertices, take advantage of [Groovy operators](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html) with something like: `l = []; (1..50).each{ l.add(graph.addVertex()) }; l`

Comment: Make sure that the configuration file `conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb-local.proper‌​ties` exists in the appropriate directory relative to where you started `gremlin.sh`. Alternatively, use a fully qualified path.

Comment: Thank U Very Much it admits their can be another way to define both 50 vertex and make connection between them by using addedge

Comment: But here is the problem now how i want to create simultaneously multiple vertex and edge and make a graph in just one CLA

Comment: conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb-local.proper‌​ties and what u are saying basically can we have to write anything on that file or just save at place TYSM for help

Comment: The `String` parameter on `TitanFactory.open(String)` is expecting a configuration file name. The configuration file is used to connect the graph to your desired backend, DynamoDB local. Read the [Javadocs](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/javadoc/current/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanFactory.html#open-java.lang.String-). [Example properties file](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/blob/1.0.0/src/test/resources/dynamodb-local.properties) from the `dynamodb-titan-storage-backend` repository.