# Create graph using data stored in DSE Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am new to DSE graphs. 
I have around 1000 records in a csv file, where each record has around 20 attributes, which I want to load in gremlin. All the records would form a separate vertex in the graph.

Is there a way to directly load all the records in one go. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889006/create-multiple-vertices-in-gremlin-graph-in-local-dynamodb) link that used storage backend as DynamoDB but that link didn't help. I have my backend as DSE Cassandra.

I also tried populating the Cassandra DB with the records and then trying to form graph using this data but it didn't work.

Please let me know if there is way to do the required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The DSE Graph Loader is a standalone tool can load CSV documents into DSE Graph. You would need to create a mapping script to use with the loader. You can find its documentation at https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglCSV.html

Comment: That doesn't help either. File.csv() is throwing this error:: 

No signature of method: static java.io.File.csv() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values

Comment: Have you successfully run any of the Datastax graph loader examples? https://github.com/datastax/graph-examples/tree/master/northwind